# How to remove X-Frame-Options?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I trying to remove X-Frame-Options from server response, but it's doesn't work.
Nginx version 1.17.8.

I use proxy_pass.
I did try like this:

```
proxy_hide_header 'x-frame-options';
```

And this:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "";
```

Also I did try with headers-more-nginx-module like this:

```
more_set_headers "x-frame-options";
```

and this:

```
more_clear_headers "X-Frame-Options";
more_clear_headers "x-frame-options";
```

And I always get an error when I trying to rendering page in iframe:

```
Refused to display 'URL_PAGE' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

Curl -I result:

```
HTTP/2 200
accept-ranges: bytes
content-security-policy: frame-src  'self' *;
content-type: text/html
date: Thu, 09 Sep 2021 16:50:50 GMT
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's more secure if you use a specific URL, for example:
`add_header X-Frame-Options "Allow-From URL";` URL should be your URL that need to make an Iframe on it.

But if you need to disable this header at all, try your first code without quote mark at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` like this:
`proxy_hide_header x-frame-options;`

Then restart your server.

Comment: This method does not work, it still has the header of x-frame-options